# How to avoid matching literals within a string and only match at the start?

Tags: java, regex

I am looking to pull data out of a log file. A typical row in the log is in this format:

```
[02 Nov 2020 17:31:00,117] [12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [            ] [0EyKACgWsiME2VoobHq2EuBc49xq_NsuBmnV0dhrgPWrKotJgQ8-!-438943902!1604338067478] [Server] DEBUG tm.BitronixTransactionManager - shutting down journal
```

The following code will create the required tokens I need in most cases:

```
String[] split = line.split("\\s+(?![^\\[]*])(?![^-]*?$)")
```

However, there are occasions where a hyphen appears within the log message as well as at the start. For example, a log message could be:

```
- shutting down journal - resetting servers
```

In the case above my current code is returning two separate strings separated by the hyphen. What I am trying to do is have the code return the full string as is above as my token for the log message.

The expected output for the split variable would be:

```
0 = "[02 Nov 2020 17:31:00,117]"
1 = "[12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)']"
2 = "[    ]"
3 = "[0EyKACgWsiME2VoobHq2EuBc49xq_NsuBmnV0dhrgPWrKotJgQ8-!-438943902!1604338067478]"
4 = "[Server]"
5 = "[DEBUG]"
6 = "[tm.BitronixTransactionManager]"
7 = "[- shutting down journal - resetting servers]"
```

Can anyone suggest how I would do this?

Comment: Please show the exact expected output for a few lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a complex regex for `split()` to separate the tokens you want, it's often easier and simpler to just capture the tokens you want:

```java
String input = "[02 Nov 2020 17:31:00,117] [12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [            ] [0EyKACgWsiME2VoobHq2EuBc49xq_NsuBmnV0dhrgPWrKotJgQ8-!-438943902!1604338067478] [Server] DEBUG tm.BitronixTransactionManager - shutting down journal - resetting servers";

for (Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[[^\\]]*\\]|-.*|\\S+").matcher(input); m.find(); ) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

*Output*

```
[02 Nov 2020 17:31:00,117]
[12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)']
[            ]
[0EyKACgWsiME2VoobHq2EuBc49xq_NsuBmnV0dhrgPWrKotJgQ8-!-438943902!1604338067478]
[Server]
DEBUG
tm.BitronixTransactionManager
- shutting down journal - resetting servers
```

*Explanation*

```
\[[^\]]*\]    Match a `[ ]` enclosed token
|             OR
-.*           Match a `-` and the rest of the input (excl. linebreaks)
|             OR
\S+           Match a block of non-space characters (must be last)
```

The `\S+` must be last, otherwise it will consume the `[` or `-` characters that are lead-in to the other two token types.

This should also perform much better, because there is no lookaheads or lookbehinds, and there is little to no backtracking.

Comment: Thank you Andreas for the solution and explanation. If I were to require one level of nested brackets would regex be suitable? E.g. [foo 123 [goo]] should output as "[foo 123 [goo]]"

Comment: @John Sure, regex can handle that, so go ahead and modify the regex to do what you want it to do.